# GRUB does not detect Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, os-prober

I have finally installed Ubuntu on my second drive. **When I start my computer GRUB only offers me to boot Ubuntu, not Windows 7.** What needs to be done so that I can choose between Ubuntu and Windows in GRUB?

When I press F12 for boot menu at startup and I choose `Windows Boot Manager` it boots into Windows 7.

---

I ran command `sudo fdisk -l` and here is log (http://pastebin.com/Cgv1igHc):

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3ffc3ff

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  1953525167   976762583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Comment: Please indicate your [Boot-Info URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info). This will provide relevant information to help you.

Comment: For me, I was getting this warning ***Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.*** after running `sudo update-grub`, [so I fixed by doing this](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/warning-os-prober-will-not-be-executed-to-detect-other-bootable-partitions/57849/2)

Answer (score 133):

1. Boot Ubuntu and **mount your Windows partition** (simply open the disk on Nautilus)
2. Run the following on the command line (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

   ```
   sudo os-prober
   ```
3. If your Windows installation was found, you can run:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

Note that step 2 is just for your convenience. You could just mount the Windows 7 partition and then run `update-grub`.

### Related question

- [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/q/145902/40581)

Comment: I have 2 partitions with 2 windows install, it only detects my install on another partition, but not the new installed windows (on a SSD)! even mounted... an idea?

Comment: Thanks.  Interesting that the os-prober seems to need step 1.  Very important, or windows won't work.

Comment: `mount -t ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sda4 /media/windows` to mount the windows partition

Comment: Thanks. I can't explain how frustrated I was till I followed this.

Answer (score 20):

If the `os-prober` method above doesn't work try adding a custom grub menu entry. Documented [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus).

First two steps are for finding your `<UUID>`.

1. Run `lsblk` and find the name of the row with `/boot/efi`

Example output *(here the answer is sda2)*:

```
lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0   450M  0 part 
├─sda2        8:2    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3        8:3    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda4        8:4    0    47G  0 part /windows
├─sda5        8:5    0 425,6G  0 part /
└─sda6        8:6    0   3,7G  0 part [SWAP]
mmcblk0     179:0    0  14,9G  0 disk 
└─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  14,9G  0 part
```

2. Run `sudo blkid /dev/sdaX` where `sdaX` is the answer from previous step *(`sda2` in my case)*.

Example output *(here the answer is 58E4-427D)*:

```
/dev/sda2: UUID="58E4-427D" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="b81727be-ba90-5f8c-ab98-d3ec67778b7d"
```

3. Add the following at the end of the file `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
menuentry "Windows 7" {  
     insmod ntfs  
     set root='(hd0,1)'  
     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set <UUID>
     chainloader +1  
}
```

4. Run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: Thanks to @Christopher Markieta for all the details in another answer. Added them to this one as well (even though the specifics of the custom entry are different.

Comment: @PhilippeGachoud `Ubuntu 20.04` in my case is not detecting the windows drive at all, and the grub is installed on another partition on the same drive as `Ubuntu`!

Answer (score 15):

I had Windows 10 running and then tried dual boot. Once Ubuntu was installed, Win 10 wasn't showing up in my GRUB loader. I tried the following --

> First of all, I disabled Secure Boot in Win10. Then ran the below
>   commands in Ubuntu :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Worked out pretty well. Was able to find both Windows and Ubuntu in GRUB after that.

Comment: Does this PPA still exist? I wasn't able to add it and it claimed it did not exist from Ubuntu 18.04 boot disk

Comment: Just received a `404 Not Found` error on Debian

Comment: If wifi is not connected it will claim it doesn't exist. This exact URL worked for me just now

Answer (score 10):

I solved a similar problem following steps of [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Install boot-repair

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Push "Recommended repair"
And put in a terminal some commands as it suggested.

I think my Grub doesn't recognize windows due to a bad shutdown, and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Slightly different method as I copied from a working example on another computer, posting for my own records.

Append the following to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
menuentry "Windows 10" {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod fat
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set <boot_efi_uuid>
        chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

where `<boot_efi_uuid>` is the UUID of your `/boot/efi` partition. To find this:

```
$ lsblk
NAME              MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT                                                  
sda                 8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk
└─md126             9:126  0 357.7G  0 raid0
  ├─md126p1       259:0    0   499M  0 md
  ├─md126p2       259:1    0   100M  0 md    /boot/efi
```

```
$ sudo blkid | grep md126p2 # Replace with your device
/dev/md126p2: UUID=<boot_efi_uuid>
```

Then of course, once you're saved the file, run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot, you should now be able to successfully start up Windows.

Comment: Thanks! FYI, according to `/etc/grub.d/README`, the filename should be `10_windows` (or similar).

Comment: I had the same issue on a raid volume, with RHEL 7. I could resolve using this answer. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

If you have previously had a RAID installed that may be causing issues. In my case, I built my desktop in 2010, and I installed two 1.5 TB with a striped RAID. [User gracemercy54 mentions here that this is left over metadata from the former RAID configuration.](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/157082)

When I originally tried the steps by Hermes I got an error specifying "wrong number of devices in a RAID set." So, if this happens to you open a terminal and run:

```
   sudo dmraid -rE
   sudo os-prober
   sudo update-grub
```

That fixed this for me.

Comment: I think mine also caused by the raid. But `sudo dmraid -rE` does not work for me. I finally made it by switch to `AHCI` in BIOS temporary, then boot to Ubuntu and execute `sudo update-grub` , then switch  `RAID ON` back.

Comment: **WARNING**: this will destroy your RAID array if you are still using it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Windows 10. I installed Linux Mint 18.1 Cinnamon 64-bit on my laptop for dual boot with WIN10. After the installation GRUB only offered to boot Linux but not Windows.

I found the video [solution for windows 10 missing from grub menu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fCA7ToywoY) and the forum thread [Grub not recognizing Win10 after Update/Repair](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=209082), but unfortunately neither worked for me so I used a combination of these two to resolve my problem.

Open your terminal and follow these commands and open the file named 40_custom:

```
sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

Add these lines to the end of the file and then save and exit:

```
menuentry "Windows 10" {
   set root='{hd0,1}'
   chainloader + 1
}
```

After you save the file update your GRUB with this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then restart your machine to see if it works.

Hope this will work for others too!

Comment: I believe that this answer while correct, is largely a copy of the answer submitted May 29, 2015

Answer (score 2):

I had issues like here above and the solution was just to add manual entry as below:

```
menuentry "WINDOWS10 (on /dev/sda1)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(/dev/sda,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 688EB92384B85968
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
```

where UUID above (688E...) was taken from boot windows disk via `blkid /dev/sdb1`.

ATTENTION: the additional line

```
set root='(/dev/sda,msdos1)'
```

refers to `sda` which is visible under Ubuntu as `/dev/sdb` even actually it is the first disk in sata bus while `/dev/sda` is in fact second drive mounted as root `/`.

Maybe that is why grub scripts could not work properly. I had no time to change the physical order of disks but it is quite possible it would help to resolve the issue, too.

Answer (score 2):

##### Edit: As @Guss specified, this should be configured in `/etc/default/grub`, not the built-in script.

Old answer:

Follow these steps if `os-prober` shows Windows, but GRUB does not.

- Edit `grub-mkconfig`

  ```
  sudo nano /usr/bin/grub-mkconfig
  ```
- Find these lines near the middle

  ```
  # Disable os-prober by default due to security reasons.
  GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="true"
  ```
- Change `true` to `false`
- Exit nano (CTRL+X, Y, Enter)
- Update GRUB

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```

Comment: With current Ubuntu LTS, you can add `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` to the `/etc/default/grub` file - which is a configuration file and won't be overwritten by an update.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and had spent 2 days figuring it out. But today I had this sudden idea in the morning and it worked out.

You should review your bios/uefi settings. In my case I had to let Uefi boot first. Otherwise I wasn't able to detect windows from ubuntu. What I had to set was ubuntu > Windows Boot Manager > DISK1 > DISK2 > DISK3. Insted DISK1 > ubuntu > Windows Boot Manager > DISK3.

I had 2 ubuntu installations one on hdd and one on ssd. Apparently ssd installation wasn't showing as UEFI for some reasone but I wanted boot faster disk first.

I wasn't expecting that order of boot can influence grub in detecting systems. So it is worth to review that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after I installed the updates from ubuntu. The following commands worked for me perfectly:

```
sudo apt-get install os-prober
```

First install os-prober to detect windows and then update grub:

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: Confirmed:  "os-prober" was missing.  This time Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia.   No error messages while running "update-grub" about missing os-prober, just failed to detect existing Windows partition.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of Bartosz Dabrowski, which lead me to solving my problem:

Be sure that if your Linux uses UEFI Boot/GPT that your other OS (eg. Windows in my case) also uses UEFI Boot/GPT. Coming from an old Win7 to Win10 installation the hard drive still had old school boot and MBR. Somehow os-prober and boot-repair had their problems to fix this.

Ensure that in BIOS / Boot order there is your HDD with ubuntu (eg. uefi: ubuntu) and your HDD with Windows Boot Manager (eg. uefi: Windows Boot Manager) to be found.

If WBM is missing ensure that windows boot disk has GPT. You can check this in Windows using Disk Management (Win + X, then Disk Management).

There is a Windows tool: mbr2gpt which can convert your MBR to GPT. After doing so (and booting via UEFI) os-prober and finally update-grub was able to find my Windows installation and added it to the boot options of grub.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I had the same problem and couldn't find a solution for me out there for a long time, finally got it, so here is my little grain of sand to the world. Before you try, remember to check you are booting using UEFI everytime you can:

Apparently, in the process of installing Debian the Windows data inside the EFI partition was lost, so what I did is a System restore using a Windows 10 USB (I tried fixing the boot but somehow it didn't work, I even tried it on console, anyways I lost no data). After this, now I coulnd't boot Debian, so I run a Debian live CD, mounted everything and chrooted like this (and don't forget to boot the USB as UEFI):

```
mount /dev/your_linux_partition /mnt
cd /mnt
mount -t proc /proc proc/
mount -t sysfs /sys sys/
mount --rbind /dev dev/
mount --rbind /sys/firmware/efi/efivars sys/firmware/efi/efivars/
mount /dev/your_efi_partition /boot/efi/
chroot /mnt /bin/bash
```

Now, here `os-prober` didn't detect Windows 10, but I decided to `grub-install /dev/sda` and `grub-update` anyways and restart.

Here is the funny thing, now I couldn't boot Windows 10 and only Debian, BUT!, I tried once again to `grub-update` and finally found the Windows 10 boot. This doesn't make any sense honestly, but I don't care. Hope it helps anyone as desperate as me :D .