# Grub not showing Windows 7 after Ubuntu 12.04 install

Tags: 12.04, grub2

I installed Ubutnu 12.04 last night, Go to boot into windows and grub only shows the option to boot into Ubuntu. Most of last night and most of this morning I have been doing research and trying different things to attempt to get Win 7 back.

Boot Info: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1464962/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GRUB does not detect Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Boot into ubuntu and then do

```
sudo os-prober
```

If os prober is not installed, before executing above command install it by doing,

```
sudo apt-get install os-prober
```

and then run the first command.
If os prober shows that you have windows along side ubuntu then do,

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot. If os prober do not show windows then something is messed up with windows.

Comment: Doesn't help, but when I reboot I hit shift so grub pops up but doesn't, if this helps heres the output from terminal:
matthewvz@Matthewvz:~$ sudo os-prober
matthewvz@Matthewvz:~$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
matthewvz@Matthewvz:~$

Comment: What are you doing man? your sudo os-prober do not output anything? It should output something. Atleast give the name of ubuntu. You are doing something wrong. 
ALso explain what is 'Doesn't Help' ? What doesnt help? WHat is the expected behaviour? What is the occured unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Wait. Do not post the same comment again and again. Read the manual for os prober. It should show an output similar to this:

`os-prober

/dev/sda5:Ubuntu 12.10 (12.10):Ubuntu:linux`

Comment: I repeated the steps again in terminal with your instructions that time but os-prober shows nothing.

Comment: That probably means you do not have another operating system on that machine. That means your windows has damaged. Also when you repeat the command and get the exact same output you do not copy paste the same output again and again you just type that you are getting the very exact same output as you got in first attempt. Was the windows working fine before installing ubuntu? 
Downlaod supergrub from here http://www.supergrubdisk.org/ burn it to usb drive or cd and then boot into live mode and see if it detects your windows. If it does detect the windows try to boot into windows.

Comment: It was working fine, from the pastebin I'm sure you saw that windows was on my ssd and I put ubuntu on my hdd. (/dev/sda was my windows drive and /dev/sdb was my linux drive).

Comment: Windows and ubuntu in two different disks ok. Was the ssd mounted ( or connected and accessible) while you exucted command osprober?

Comment: It was mounted when I did the osprober