# Installed Ubuntu 15.04 alongside Win8 with something else option in a new partition of HDD. But Ubuntu starts directly without letting me choose an OS

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I am a Windows 8.1 user. I want to use dual boot with Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu 15.04 with the **Something Else** option. Installed correctly in swap and ext4. When I start the PC Ubuntu boots. But I want to select win 8 or Ubuntu OS. During the installation of Ubuntu it showed a warning, something about BIOS UEFI mode.

Now how can I solve this problem? What setting can I use to be able to choose an OS to boot?

My motherboard is Gigabyte H81M-S2PV

Comment: Does the Ubuntu boot menu come up, asking you to choose between Ubuntu or Advanced Options for Ubuntu?

Comment: Run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) (part of the `boot-info-script` package in Ubuntu, IIRC). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to a [pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post a link to your document there to this site. Without the information from `RESULTS.txt` (or equivalent information gathered in other ways), any answer will be guesswork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This warning says as well, that you probably  wont be able to boot any other OS:

[image: error]

I would give [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) a try:

I would read [the Ubuntu help wiki UEFI page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) as well, as it mentions starting Ubuntu installation in Legacy mode instead of UEFI:

And if that doesn't work for you, read:

[Installing ubuntu 14.04 along with windows 8 in legacy mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591763/installing-ubuntu-14-04-along-with-windows-8-in-legacy-mode)

Comment: Yes this Question was appear during Installation. And I pressed go Back without being concern. Now I need to Repair boot , right ?

Comment: Yes,  use Boot-Repair tool and follow steps from second link...I personally would start with: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Converting_Ubuntu_into_UEFI_or_Legacy_mode, but its always better to read the whole thing and start from beginning

Comment: I repaired boot successfully using Boot Repair tool. Now OS selection menu shows every pc on time. But there is no Windows 8 option. only Ubuntu, advance setting for Ubuntu and system setup, this three option appear. 
After boot repair this is my boot script: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10963332/

Comment: Try to edit grub manualy with: https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer and add Windows...its safer than editing via text editor. ..... I have never dealt with this kind of problem so I dont want to suggest anything dangerous...if it was my system I would make it work via trial and error method...you can always easily repair grub with live CD... from what I can tell Linux is on Efi boot, it boots from sdb and windows is classic MBR, so conversion might be an answer. Im novice to linux so dont take my word for it...