# I wanted to make duel boot. I had GRUB/Boot problem. I repaired boot using Boot-Repair tool. But In OS selcetion, there is only Ubuntu no Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I am new in Linux. My First Problem : [I install Ubuntu 15.04 using Something else option in a new Partition of HDD. But Ubuntu start Directly without let me chose boot option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615812/i-install-ubuntu-15-04-using-something-else-option-in-a-new-partition-of-hdd-bu) I have Repaired boot using Boot-repair tool. Now problem is there is no windows 8 option in OS selection time. 
I want to list with windows 8 and Ubuntu. Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You should run from terminal*

`sudo update-grub`

*The grub will read the both OS installed on you harddisk*

Comment: Enjoy with ubuntu