# How to restore Dell M3800 Developer Edition

Tags: dell, restore

How do I completely restore Ubuntu to factory on the Dell M3800 Developer Edition? I know that there is some Dell Recovery Linux Tool, but how do I even access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On the bootloader there is an option to reset to factory settings. Assuming that you didn't also break the bootloader, you should be able to still do this. Once you turn on the computer as soon as you get the purple screen press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, this will show you some options for booting, and one of them should be something like "Reset to Factory Settings".

<sub>**Source:** http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/os-applications/f/4613/t/19620838</sub>

#### Ubuntu on Dell Precision M3800

The Dell driver download webpage for the Dell Precision M3800 Workstation only has drivers for Windows 7 and Windows 8.1. The following results are found at the [Ubuntu on Dell Precision M3800](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201409-15517/) webpage at the official ubuntu.com website. The Dell Precision M3800 Workstation that has Ubuntu 14.04 preinstalled ships on pre-configured hardware, so you do not get the same choice of hardware options that you get on the Dell Precision M3800 Mobile Workstations that ship with Windows preinstalled. If your laptop has Ubuntu 14.04 preinstalled, it is supported by updates until April, 2019, so you don't need to upgrade or reinstall the operating system for a long time.

**Proprietary drivers**

- Nvidia GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M] - The Recommended driver for this GPU can be found from the terminal by running the command `ubuntu-drivers devices` and then installed from the default Ubuntu repositories.
- NVIDIA Prime - The Dell Precision M3800 supports NVIDIA Prime switchable graphics (*nvidia-prime*) from the default Ubuntu repositories. To switch NVIDIA Prime switchable graphics from a GUI you also need to install NVIDIA X Server Settings (*nvidia-settings*) from the Ubuntu Software Center.
- Intel Wireless 7260 - Most Intel wireless adapters use the built-in open source drivers that are bundled with the default Ubuntu installation.