# Dell M3800 14.04 to 14.10 messed up

Tags: updates, 14.10

I just restored to a fresh copy of 14.04. Setup the computer installed all my plug-ins and essentials updated everything and cleaned up then when I tried to update to 14.10 everything went fairly smoothly until a couple errors popped up (one had something to do with `dpkg`) I don't exactly remember what they were.

But I hit continue and after it all finished it said the update had completed but there were problems. It restarted the computer but just to a purple screen with caps lock blinking.

I restarted and booted to the recovery setting and choose to try to repair the computer. After doing that I rebooted and it booted to 14.10 however now the computer is really messed up and almost nothing is working.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have any other operating systems installed on the Dell M3800 besides Ubuntu? Some models of Dell M3800 that come with Ubuntu preinstalled have a factory reset option, if you don't care about deleting any other dual boot or multiboot OSs that you have installed.

Comment: No I haven't installed any other operating systems yet. I already have tried doing the factory reset then going over the whole installation process again but the same thing happened when I tried to update.

Comment: Ok. The one thing is that the recovery is a Dell recovery tool that's built in. I would assume that it would probably contain the Dell drivers.  Would it not? Becuase after the first restore the computer was working perfectly fine before I tried to update it

Comment: The built-in Dell recovery tool would contain the Dell drivers for that version of Ubuntu current to when the laptop was manufactured, but it wouldn't contain the latest versions of the same Dell drivers. Also you need to know the difference between the words update and upgrade. Update means to update only the packages. Upgrade means to upgrade the entire OS to a more recent version - example from Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10 or from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. You can only upgrade an LTS release to either the next version or the next LTS version. The current LTS releases are Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I deleted some old comments, which breaks up the continuity of the discussion and moved the important information about how to install the proprietary drivers into [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/618733/how-to-restore-dell-m3800-developer-edition/618736#618736) which is also where I will be adding more information to it if necessary.