# How to delete an "Install Alongside Windows" so I can install it properly in its own partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I just installed Ubuntu 14.0.4 using [this Livewire guide](https://www.lifewire.com/ultimate-windows-8-1-ubuntu-dual-boot-guide-2200654) and realized about halfway through the installer's screens that it hadn't asked me what partition I wanted to use (i had 460gig and 40gig on C, 1TB on D. I wanted it on the 40gig.) The back buttons wouldn't let me go far enough to fix this, so I kept clicking continue and booted into Ubuntu to see where I was.

I was on the 460gig partition, along with all of Windows 10. How can I undo this and install Ubuntu to the 40gig partition? (If you can help me revert this to the previous configuration, I think I should have used [this guide](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/) to install instead.)

I don't know if it's related, but the boot selector did not boot Windows when it was selected; I had to go into the BIOS and change the order back to checking Windows MBR first.

I don't have a disk clone backup, but I also don't have any data on here to prevent a full erase and reinstall Windows if that's what it takes.

PS: This should be tagged `re-installation`for repairing a previous installation but it kept throwing the "can't use installation tag" error.

Comment: If you selected install alongside Windows then I don't think it will install it _inside_ the windows partition, it should have shrunk your 460gig partition and installed it next to it, are you sure it has installed it inside the Windows partition?

Comment: Looking in (windows) disk management, it now shows 5 partitions on that disk: the 500 and 100mb recovery partitions, a 437GB NTFS C: drive, a 23.10GB unnamed drive, and a 15.96GB unnamed drive. That all sums to 480GB which I think is the actual size of the disk once you account for the GB/GbB weirdness. So… Linux partitioned itself?

Comment: Yes that sounds about right, Ubuntu partitioned your empty 40GB partition to another 16GB partition and installed itself in there. Unfortunately this isn't much space but if it's workable then you can expand Windows to take up the leftover 23GB and carry on from there.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Can you tell me what terms I need to search for to troubleshoot the boot selector not loading windows problem? I don't really want to change the BIOS every time I swap OSs. (ETA: I can find a lot of stuff talking about grub, but my BIOS says I don't have grub, only "ubuntu")

Comment: The boot selector is called the GRUB this [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows#198875) answer :)

Comment: thank you very much, i'll follow that and hopefully it will work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu would not have installed inside of your Windows partition, chances are it has partitioned the spare 40GB again and installed inside of that.

I am not sure why it did not pickup the Windows installation in the GRUB, but you could try following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows#198875) answer to fix it