# Ubuntu 18.04 Server unable to see Windows 10 OS as dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

**My machine config:**

> Threadripper 1950x 16-core  +  Gigabyte X399 aorus 7
>
> 32GB DDR4
>
> Samsung NVME 960 512GB
>
> UEFI mode with GPT partition scheme

Windows 10 Pro + Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS

I previously had Windows 10 + Ubuntu 16.04 Server as dual boot and I never had any problems.

**What I did so far:**

1) I Installed Windows 10 x64 Pro (1803) on my machine - no problems

2) I tried to install Ubtunu 18.04 Server as dual boot but it did not detect existing windows OS. Tried multiple boots but no luck so finally installed Ubuntu causing windows wiped out

3) Then I installed Windows 10 (as dual boot) without disturbing Ubuntu partitions. No problems

4) Now only windows 10 boots so I followed [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) and fixed the issue but now Only Ubuntu boots

5) Then I followed [GRUB does not detect Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows)  but it STILL does NOT detect Windows 10 OS but I can mount the windows 
partition on Ubuntu. os-prober also sees the Windows OS but grub doesn't!
Please see below and advise, Many thanks!

```
root@ubuntu18:~# mkdir -p /media/windows
root@ubuntu18:~#  fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 01BADB0F-4C8E-4332-BA18-822F08CE451B
Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1050624 361760767 360710144   172G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 361760768 370149375   8388608     4G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p4 370149376 370182143     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p5 370182144 976773119 606590976 289.3G Microsoft basic data
root@ubuntu18:~#
root@ubuntu18:~# mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/nvme0n1p5 /media/windows/
root@ubuntu18:~# os-prober
/dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi
root@ubuntu18:~# update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
root@ubuntu18:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  1.6M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2  169G  1.7G  158G   2% /
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4486
/dev/nvme0n1p1  511M   29M  483M   6% /boot/efi
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0
/dev/nvme0n1p5  290G  187G  104G  65% /media/windows
```

but no luck, Please advise.

Comment: Did you have Windows fast start up off? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: Yes, I always shutdown windows 10 fully. No hibernation, thanks!

Comment: Shutdown is not the same as turning off fast start up. Standard shutdown uses fast start up (hibernation) since Windows boots so slow. And Windows turns fast start up back on with updates, so even if you turned it off before, if Windows has updated, even in background fast start may be back on.

Comment: Was the NVMe drive in your BIOS set to AHCI or RAID?

Comment: @oldfred - I might have expressed it wrongly but I know what that setting is. It is under "choose what the power buttons do" which I UNchecked, thanks!

Comment: All I know is the screen shots in the link in the first comment.  Many  think just full shutdown works, but unless settings are changed it  still uses fast start up. And updates keep turning fast start up back on. Older gigabyte boards also needed IOMMU turned off. You may need this since system is so new AMD 18.20 preview driver. https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Radeon-Software-18.20-Preview Driver at: https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Radeon-Software-for-Linux-18.20-Early-Preview-Release-Notes.aspx

Comment: Don't fret, dual boot Windows 10 pro and Ubuntu 18.04 works. Install Windows 10 first then shrinked the Windows partition to create a free space for installing Ubuntu. As long as Ubuntu can see the free space you are good. Create a partition on the free space and install ubuntu and grub2 on that paritition, never let ubuntu touch the windows boot manager that launch from the windows EFI partition. Both Windows 10 and Ubuntu will be visible in BIOS EFI boot or Windows boot selection. You can tinker it with efibootmgr from Ubuntu later for boor order or next boot target.

Answer (score -1):

I think this **must be a bug** of 18.04.

1) I rebuilt my machine from scratch with WIndows 10 (clean) - No problems.

2) I installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 as dual boot - every thing worked straight forward. Detected windows 10 and grub setup was done and dual boot working fine.

3) I installed Ubuntu Server 17.10 on top of same Ubuntu partitions (not upgrade) alongwith dual boot of same WIndows 10 - No problems - worked straight forward.

4) Please note both #2 & #3 - I have tried with windows settings of Fast boot off & on. Irrespective of this setting, I was able to install both Ubuntu versions (16.x & 17.x) without any problems

5) But Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't even see the Windows partition and/or Windows 10 OS while installing it. It simply overwrites it (even though I chose manual partitioning). Please see below screenshot

[Screenshot of ubuntu 18.04 installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tb4R.png)

6) As I needed to run 18.04 - I freshly installed 17.10 and did a "do-release-upgrade" and it upgraded to 18.04 without any problems. All good now.

7) If anyone could please reproduce this issue(with similar setup) and report, it would be great, Many thanks!!

Comment: Please don't speculate that is a bug as some have successfully install dual boot system with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 including myself. I have Windows 10 pro came pre-installed on my laptop, and installing 18.04 simply require the Windows volumne to be resized to make room for Ubuntu installation (done via USB). Secure boot enable for both and configured for EFI boot. I think there are specifc problems when it doesn't work and let's try to figure things out instead of saying that it's a bug.

Comment: THIS is exactly my problem. I thought it was me but when I try and install Ubuntu Server as dual boot with WIn 10, it seems the install does not see the 'free space' that I have set aside for the ubuntu. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @BernardWei did you read my entire posts and understand them?? I even tried legacy bios mode (MBR disk) and tried and I still face same problem with Ubuntu 18.04 & 18.10. I disabled windows fastboot, hibernate & also bios fast boot. With the same setup, Ubuntu 16.x works PERFECTLY STRAIGHT forward without ANY problem. but Both 18.04 & 10 are NOT able to see the windows partitions. Please advise. thanks!

Comment: @peteubuntu did you get any solution for our problem? I tried in both UEFI & legacy modes and same issue with both 18.04 & 18.10 but no issues at all with 16.x

Comment: @Bateman Yes, you have found a workaround for the problem which is great. But speculating that this is a bug in Ask Ubuntu without providing a link to a bug report is not a good practise. If you wish to raise a bug report, please check this first. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs