# How to install Ubuntu 18.04 along with Windows 10 in Legacy BIOS Mode?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, 18.04

I am using Windows 10, recently I want to move Ubuntu 18.04, and for some reason I can't completely uninstall Windows 10 now, So I want to use Ubuntu 18.04 along with Windows 10. But the problem is: When I run the Ubuntu Installation, it does not show **Install Ubuntu alongside Windows**. Which is expected by me, as previously I've used Ubuntu [ From 15.10 to 17.10 ] with Windows 7. So I don't try **Something Else** option to install Ubuntu, because I am in fear if I won't access Windows 10 from GRUB.

Anyway, currently Windows 10 is installed in Legacy BIOS mode & I think Ubuntu want UEFI.

So, can anyone tell me, is it possible to install Ubuntu in Legacy Mode? If yes than how?

Comment: I’m not sure, but your problem may be related to this (Ubuntu installer doesn’t see Windows): https://askubuntu.com/q/1032170/630335

Comment: Just to double check, can you confirm your disk is set as AHCI in the BIOS?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes!
I had the same problem and solved it by using [Universal USB Installer](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3)
that uses legacy mode.

I found out about Universal USB Installer and the fact that it writes to the USB in legacy mode from [this recent post](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver-on-uefi-and-legacy-bios-system.html) on It'zGeek in a section under Step 2, describing how to "Create a bootable USB disk" with Windows.

When I booted from this image, then the legacy Windows 10 installation was recognized and I was able to install Ubuntu 18.04.  The only condition is that Universal USB installer is a Windows program, so I had to use Windows to make the legacy mode Ubuntu 18.04 live USB, which is not a big deal.

Comment: thanks for your response. After install, did you find any option to boot Windows 10 in GRUB Bootloader?

Comment: Yes, the option is there and it works.

Comment: OK, I will try. let's see what will be the output.