# grub and os-prober don't see Windows10 after upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, os-prober

Can be related to [Ubuntu 18.04 Server unable to see Windows 10 OS as dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032170/ubuntu-18-04-server-unable-to-see-windows-10-os-as-dual-boot/1139224#1139224)

My Initial configuration: Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 on separate drive since 16.04 release. No problem,both on grub menu.

I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 through the builtin upgrader.
Windows 10 disappeared from grub menu and os-prober doesn't see it. Windows 10 is still there though and can be accessed through the BIOS boot order. Is there any way for me to fix it or is it a 18.04 bug? Also please let me know if some diagnostics could be run in order to find the cause of this (small) problem.
JF