# GRUB cannot find Windows partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

Yesterday, I installed Ubuntu 18 on my laptop. Before installing, I had a dual-boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16, yet now I don't have the option for Windows - instead, I have Ubuntu 18 (+settings), Ubuntu 16 (+settings) and "System Setup".

I can still view the Windows files through Nautilus.
I tried searching through countless questions here, yet none worked.

Is there a way to make Windows appear in GRUB again?

[Log #1](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/37VR6SbhHz/)

[Log #2](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rvrSwC8vRZ/)

EDIT: After referring to the comments below, I have somehow managed to add an option for "Windows 7" (even though I have W10) which does not work.

Comment: Did you try [these answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows)?

Comment: I have tried them, none worked for me so far. Will keep trying but so far nothing.

Comment: You need to move boot flag back to sda1 with gparted. Then with Boot-Repair install Windows boot loader, so you can boot Windows and turn off fast start up. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions With BIOS/MBR configuration, boot flag must only be on NTFS partition with Windows boot files. Grub does not use boot flag. And only if UEFI install would boot flag be on an ESP, but you have Windows & Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode.

Comment: @oldfred didn't manage to install Windows Boot Loader and access Windows 10. Anything I can do?

Comment: Just run the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair