# Grub won't show Windows 10 but it shows Windows Boot Manager

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I'm trying to start using Ubuntu. I already had Windows 10 in my hdd, I made a new partition for Ubuntu 18.04 and then installed it. Both OS are in the same hdd but in different partitions, but when I boot it shows the grub and it won't show Windows 10 option, it shows Windows Boot Manager (and if I pick this it will let me boot in Windows but it's slow). I already tried `os-prober` (from this question: [GRUB does not detect Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows)) and this is what it shows

```
/dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi
```

when I use `fdisk -l` this is what it shows (in Spanish, I'm sorry)

```
Disco /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectores
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Tipo de etiqueta de disco: gpt
Identificador del disco: C271E36A-B1BA-4B61-9C48-B90831A729D5

Dispositivo   Comienzo      Final   Sectores Tamaño Tipo
/dev/sda1         2048    1023999    1021952   499M Entorno de recuperación de Windows
/dev/sda2      1024000    1226751     202752    99M Sistema EFI
/dev/sda3      1226752    1259519      32768    16M Reservado para Microsoft
/dev/sda4      1259520 1187666070 1186406551 565.7G Datos básicos de Microsoft
/dev/sda5   1187667968 1953523711  765855744 365.2G Sistema de ficheros de Linux
```

I'm not sure what should I do or what all of these means, I'm not used to linux.

In BIOS I have secure boot and legacy support both disabled. I already made sure hibernate option is disabled in Windows