# windows 7 option not shown in grub with dual boot ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I installed 18.04.3 LTS along with windows 7.After installation I tried installing some software and corrupted my ubuntu by mistake. I went back and reinstalled ubuntu.I selected this [option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz05N.png) to replace the existing ubuntu.After this my windows 7 did not appear in the grub as well as in the boot menu when I press F12 and it directly boots into ubuntu.I tried the "sudo update-grub" command but it does not work. My windows os files still exist.I can access them through the file manager on ubuntu.Hope I will get a solution.
This is my boot info summary:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/s5nbYjH9GS/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GRUB does not detect Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows)

Comment: This is the old problem of Windows set up to run in Legacy BIOS, while  Ubuntu here is running for a UEFI BIOS mode. The two booting systems required are different and incompatible, and Windows must have a GPT formatted disk if it is to work with UEFI. Ideally you should have both OS running in UEFI but you'd need to convert your disk to GPT format and then a re-install of Windows.