# Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on separate drives, Windows 10 won't start

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a separate external drive along with my Windows 10. The Ubuntu installation is successful but I can no longer boot Windows 10, not even from the BIOS using boot override. The files seem to be intact since I can mount the drive and look through the files. It also doesn't show up in the GRUB menu.

I have tried the solutions given by [GRUB does not detect Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows) but the os-prober doesn't find my Windows installation. `lsblk` shows the partitions but there is no `/boot/efi` as shown in the following result.

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  14,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/296
loop1    7:1    0   3,7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/100
loop2    7:2    0  65,9M  1 loop /snap/discord/101
loop3    7:3    0  42,8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313
loop4    7:4    0 181,1M  1 loop /snap/spotify/36
loop5    7:5    0 136,9M  1 loop /snap/code/20
loop6    7:6    0     4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/406
loop7    7:7    0  1008K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/61
loop8    7:8    0 149,9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/67
loop9    7:9    0  88,5M  1 loop /snap/core/7270
loop10   7:10   0  54,4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1066
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   128M  0 part 
└─sda2   8:2    0 931,4G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   450M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0    99M  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0    16M  0 part 
├─sdb4   8:20   0 231,8G  0 part 
└─sdb5   8:21   0   517M  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0 931,5G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0 931,5G  0 part /
```

Why am I unable to boot my Windows 10?

*EDIT*: As suggested by Paul Benson here are the outputs for `grep -i -A10 windows /boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

```bsh
$ grep -i -A10 windows /boot/grub/grub.cfg
menuentry "Windows 10" {
   set root='{hd0,1}'
   chainloader + 1
}

### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
```

And `sudo fdisk -l|grep -A4 /dev/sd`:

```
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Disk /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
--
/dev/sda1      34     262177     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2  264192 1953523711 1953259520 931,4G Microsoft basic data



Disk /dev/sdb: 232,9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
--
/dev/sdb1       2048    923647    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sdb2     923648   1126399    202752    99M EFI System
/dev/sdb3    1126400   1159167     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb4    1159168 487335654 486176487 231,8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb5  487335936 488394751   1058816   517M Windows recovery environment


Disk /dev/sdc: 931,5 GiB, 1000170586112 bytes, 1953458176 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
--
/dev/sdc1  *     2048 1953456127 1953454080 931,5G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/loop8: 149,9 MiB, 157184000 bytes, 307000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
```

Comment: @karel I went through the linked answers but they don't provide a valid/sufficient solution. I feel like the main issue is that i have no partition listed as /boot/efi.

Comment: You do have an ESP partition at sdb2.  Need to see the output of `grep -i -A10 windows /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Also need to see the output of `grep -i -A10 windows /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Also change the output of *fdisk result* to `sudo fdisk -l|grep -A4 /dev/sd`.

Comment: @PaulBenson I have edited my post so it contains the results you asked for.

Comment: Please don't put screenshots of text. Rather copy and paste the text output directly in the question. Then highlight the pasted text and format it as code using the { } icon above the edit question window.

Comment: @user68186 I have put the outputs as text in the question as suggested.

Comment: You have 3 disks. It looks like Ubuntu is on sdc, Windows on sdb and what is sda for? Anyway the problem is your grub file as it shows W10 set up on a GPT disk, but coded to run on an MBR disk, ie run in Legacy Bios which isn't possible. Yet Ubuntu on sdc is set up as an MBR disk but appears to boot from Legacy Bios. Can you confirm in what mode you are currently using your computer, ie UEFI or LB?

Comment: @PaulBenson The computer seems to be currently running in Legacy Bios. Just a side note to your remark, Ubuntu is indeed on sdc, windows on sdb and sda is just another internal drive for general storage (without os).

Comment: OK. That's why W10 isn't recognised. You need to re-install Ubuntu. Before you do that switch over to UEFI then boot into Live Ubuntu, and run Gparted. Choose sdc then click on Device tab->Create Partition Table. You are now going to convert sdc to a GPT drive. Choose *gpt*. **Everything on sdc will now be wiped**. Then   re-install Ubuntu makong 2 primary ext4 partitions on sdc, one for *Root*, another for *Home*.

Comment: @PaulBenson That seems to have done the trick, thank you very much. If you could post your answer as an answer to this question then I can accept it as an answer, otherwise I'll quote you as an answer to myself.

Comment: @Bullseye  I'm glad it worked. I'll post up an answer in a few hours from now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common problem when setting up a dual boot with Windows/Ubuntu for the first time is that you find that you can only boot into one system or the other, in this case Ubuntu. There may be several reasons for this, but the most common one I've seen is where 2 disks are used to install each system respectively, and one disk is formatted to DOS and the other to GPT.

First thing to do if booted in Ubuntu or in Live  Ubuntu is inspect your partitions. Run `sudo fdisk -l|grep -A4 /dev/sd` which will not only show you all the details of what is stored on your partitions but also whether the disk is formatted in GPT or DOS (which is the old MBR format of how disk partitions are arranged).

Here we know the computer is being run in Legacy Bios mode, but for Windows 10 we have disk *sdb* formatted to GPT. The 2 states are incompatible. W10 installed on a GPT disk must be run in UEFI mode, or the disk will not be recognised. However Ubuntu here set up on disk *sdc* is a DOS disk format. On it's own, even if run in UEFI BIOS it doesn't cause an issue. But with a dual boot, having one disk in DOS and another in GPT format usually ends up only allowing the user to boot to one system.

The best solution therefore would be to convert the Ubuntu DOS disk to GPT as it's the more modern format that allows more than 4 primary partitions to be made (DOS has a limit of 4). It does mean a re-install of Ubuntu as converting a disk to GPT wipes everything on it. There's no point in changing the Windows disk back to a DOS format and running in Legacy BIOS which is the older system as well as the added complication of re-installing W10 which is more involved and would take a much longer time to achieve.

So to do this have your Live Ubuntu USB drive ready. Go into BIOS and switch it to UEFI if in Legacy BIOS. Then boot into your USB and run Gparted. Choose sdc if that is shown as the disk containing the Ubuntu installation. You are now going to convert sdc to a GPT drive. Click on Device tab->Create Partition Table.  Choose GPT. Everything on sdc will now be wiped. Then re-install Ubuntu making 2 primary ext4 partitions on sdc, one for Root, another for Home, and let the installation proceed, and reboot.