# GRUB doesn't find Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, ssd

I know there are plenty of similar questions but no solution worked. 
I installed Ubuntu on a new HDD and have Windows 10 installed on another SSD. Win 10 is installed in legacy mode and Ubuntu too.

For certain reasons there are 2 additional HDDs each with Windows 10 installed (they aren't bootable anymore - don't ask why please :D). GRUB does find these two Windows 10 installations but not my actual Windows 10 installation.

Neither `sudo os-prober` nor `sudo update grub` show my SSD Windows 10. The SSD is mounted and I tried adding it manually like proposed here: [GRUB does not detect Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows)

Strangely enough BIOS only shows me my Windows 10 SSD as boot option but I can manually boot the Ubuntu HDD.

Sorry if I didn't use the correct terminology.

EDIT: Fast boot is disabled.

Comment: I don't know if it a similar situation that I am facing. Whenever I do an update-grub, or do an update, grub finds the Ubuntu installations very very fast, but it takes a very long time (I'm guessing up to 5 minutes) before it eventually finds my Windows installation. Good luck. Paul

Comment: @Paul Thanks for the hint but that didn't work. I am just selecting the Ubuntu HDD when I am booting my PC as a "solution".