# Triple boot - GRUB doesn't detect Windows 7 (it can just see Windows 10)

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, windows-7

I have just configured a triple boot with Windows 10, Windows 7 and Ubuntu 19.10 on my SSD. Below you can see the disk details.

GParted:

[image]

Unfortunately GRUB can't detect Windows 7.

GRUB Customizer:

[image]

Comment: Here is a link to an old question that may lead you to an answer. [dual boot - GRUB does not detect Windows - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows)

Comment: Windows only boots in BIOS mode from the one primary NTFS partition with the boot flag. And the BCD is then where you choose which Windows to boot. Since your Windows 7 has no boot files, grub2's os-prober cannot find it. If it was in a primary partition you could move boot flag & run Windows repairs to add boot files. Not sure if just adding Windows 7 boot files would work or not (Win10 will not work). Grub could find it, but it may not boot. you may be able to convert sda5 to a primary partition since all others could be in extended. Then you could repair your Win7 install.

Comment: I solved. I gave up on the idea of manteining Windows 7 and I formatted again my disk. now I have a dual boot with W10 and Ubuntu (either placed in a primary partition).