# Neither GRUB Nor Windows Recognize Each Other

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

SOLVED: I mis-installed it. Thanks David.

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside a preexisting Win10 installation. Now, neither OS recognizes the other's presence. I can miraculously use both, but it's a hassle and all the fixes I've found haven't worked. I have tried various fixes for both issues:

When I boot and go into startup menu > boot device options, I'm faced with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP7rK.jpg) (first image) the bottom option "Notebook hard drive" starts GRUB and I can get into Ubuntu normally. But why isn't it recognized as Ubuntu?
If I don't go into the boot menu and let the computer do its thing, it goes to Windows automatically. The second image shows what happens if I go into the BIOS boot options. There's that "notebook hard drive" option under "Legacy boot order", but I can't seem to turn that on. I already have secure boot turned off, as you see.

Getting the computer to start directly into GRUB would presently be disastrous anyway, because GRUB in turn doesn't recognize Windows and I'd be unable to use it! I've tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows) (second answer, "If the os-prober method doesn't work...") and indeed, now there's a Windows 10 entry. But selecting it gives me a black screen with the text `An operating system wasn't found. Try disconnecting any drives that don't contain an operating system. Press any key to restart`
Note that I don't actually have any rows in my `lsblk` output with `/boot/efi` in them, but `/dev/sda2` has an appropriate label:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  55,5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1988
loop1    7:1    0  55,5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1997
loop2    7:2    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
loop3    7:3    0  64,8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
loop4    7:4    0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/518
loop5    7:5    0  31,1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11036
loop6    7:6    0  32,3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11588
sda      8:0    0 447,1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   499M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0    99M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0 186,3G  0 part /home/kilian/Windows
├─sda5   8:5    0   603M  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0 186,3G  0 part /
└─sda7   8:7    0    15M  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

/dev/sda2: UUID="C495-5A59" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system  partition"PARTUUID="6795db25-5a95-4724-a256-4b7cf3c60931"
```

Last thing I tried just now was the `boot-repair` tool suggested below the custom GRUB entry in the AskUbuntu post I linked. I got this:

WindowsEFI detected. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB) that is compatible with UEFI booting mode. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit ([www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd](http://www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd)), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode.

Anyway, before I continue trying out fixes that work on either problem in isolation - is this even two separate problems? Or are both linked to the same issue, did I do something fundamentally wrong when partitioning my SSD? Has anyone encountered this particular problem?

Comment: Sounds like you installed 1 OS with BIOS and the other in EFI mode. This is the typical result.

Comment: So, no way to change it except re-installing Ubuntu? At which part of the installation process would I have had to choose between BIOS and EFI?

Comment: When you made the live boot media you needed to match the install mode of the already present Windows install.

Comment: Windows never recocnizes Ubuntu, because Ubuntu is (normally) installed on ext4 and windows doen't understand ext4

Comment: Not why it is because BIOS does not see EFI and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very common mistake.

Sounds like you installed 1 OS with BIOS and the other in EFI mode. This is the typical result.

The best thing to do is to re make the live media to match the mode of the already installed Windows OS and re install Ubuntu.

If the install modes had matched the Ubuntu install would have seen the existing Windows OS and asked you if you wanted to install beside it.

Then you would have Grub that would let you choose OS on start up.

Comment: If Windows is UEFI on gpt partitioned drive & Ubuntu on same gpt partitioned drive in BIOS boot mode, you do not have to do a total reinstall. Boot-Repair when booted in UEFI mode using its advanced mode can totally purge the BIOS boot version of grub grub-pc and install the UEFI version of grub - grub-efi-amd64, converting install from BIOS to UEFI. If on separate MBR drive, better to convert drive to gpt and totally reinstall.

Comment: Yes I agree. I was offering what I felt was a more practical method for the OP. Both have the potential to work.