# After installing Ubuntu, can't boot Windows 8 at all!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, windows-8

I had Windows 8 running and then tried dual boot. Once Ubuntu was installed, Win 8 wasn't showing up in my GRUB loader, also not in the original laptop Boot Loader (Windows Boot Loader? - from there I can start towards ubuntu too).

I tried more or less all methods proposed in [GRUB does not detect Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows) as well as in similar questions (sorry to "ask again": solutions proposed were not succesful in my case), inclusive boot-repair: here is the log: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6vFGKFKpbH/

Still not able to find Windows 8 in GRUB after that (only ubuntu).
Looks like os-prober can't detect windows on my /dev/sda2 partition. Any clues ?

Here is how my partitions look like:

```
Disk sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0xe8d8a8f3
      Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1               63  130672709  130672647  62.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda2        130674686 1897490431 1766815746 842.5G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
sda3  *    1897490432 1928740863   31250432  14.9G 83 Linux
sda4       1928740864 1953523711   24782848  11.8G 83 Linux
sda5        130674688  130781183     106496    52M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda6        130785228  831170969  700385742   334G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda7        831171033 1889677754 1058506722 504.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda8       1889679360 1897490431    7811072   3.7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

sda2 with 842.5G doesn't sound right...

Where is the issue?
Thanks in advance for advice!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: Thanks @karel ! I am looking into it.